# Getting an error on pivot table using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I did pivot table from normal datatable using linq. However sometimes, i get an errors like;

```
There is no row at position 5(or any number like 7,8,11 etc..)
-----------------------------------------------------------
object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

What i didn't understand it, Why sometimes it works very well, with the same conditions like 'sample_time' etc. and why sometimes doesn't work.

Here is the my code to swap rows to columns with linq. Also when i debug, I found the part that throws an error.

```
 var dtExist = dtTopAll.AsEnumerable().Where(l => l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") >= minDate && l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") <= maxDate).Any();

            if (dtExist == true)
            {
                var dt = (from dr1 in dtTopAll.AsEnumerable()
                          where dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") >= minDate && dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") <= maxDate
                          group dr1 by new
                          {
                              WAIT_CLASS = dr1.Field<string>("WAIT_CLASS"),
                              SAMPLE_TIME = dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME")
                          } into g
                          select new
                          {
                              SAMPLE_TIME = g.Key.SAMPLE_TIME,
                              WAIT_CLASS = g.Key.WAIT_CLASS,
                              WAITS = g.Sum(z => z.Field<double>("WAITS") / 100)
                          }).ToDataTable();

                var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME")).ToList();

                foreach (var group in groups) // From this line to end, throws an error .
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dtPivotCustom.Rows.Add();
                    newRow[0] = group.Key;
                    foreach (string item in items)
                    {
                        newRow[item] = group.Where(x => x.Field<string>("WAIT_CLASS") == item).Select(x => x.Field<double>("WAITS")).Sum();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This requires debugging, however - notice that the line before: `var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME")).ToList();` is linq. This means it is calculated only one first access. In this example, it is calculated when you first handle the 'foreach'. Look for your error there.

Comment: @OriNachum what should be the correct way. Probably you are right. Could you write as an answer ?

Comment: Rereading this I see I missed the `.ToList()` which supposed to give you direct answer. Did you verify it's not empty?

Comment: @OriNachum yes, its totally full.

Comment: Instead of `foreach` change it to `for` and before accessing the data, verify it's not null. Maybe it's missing in Excel. For the same run, the item changes, right?

Comment: @OriNachum yes, i will try for it.